# ¿Como reemplazar el resultado de la ejecución en una función en Google Apps Script por su resultado?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una función personalizada que consulta en una base de datos el nombre de una persona algo como:

```
   Nombre
   =nombre(1234)
```

Me devuelve algo como

```
   Nombre
   John Doe
```

Necesito que solamente se ejecute una vez la consulta en la base de datos y el valor de la función quede en la celda es decir que al pararme en la celda aparezca `John Doe` y no `=nombre(1234)`.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, estoy dispuesto a implementar una función en Google Apps Script ó de ser posible usar una función predefinida en Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

En las hojas de cálculo de Google las funciones personalizadas no pueden hacer eso. Una opción es que en lugar de una función personalizada uses una actividor "al editar" (on edit). Otra opción sería que en lugar de llamar la función por un activador lo hagas ya sea desde el editor de scripts, un menú personalizado, un dibujo al que le asignes una función o una diálogo o barra lateral.

La mejor solución depende de la forma en la que pretendas que se use tu hoja de cálculo.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers